# Equations whose terms are multiple lines of text

Tags: equations, lyx, multirow, text

I would like to write a text equation like this:

[image: Text equation example]

The terms of the equation are text and every one should be written in several lines.

Until now I am able to write the equation with text terms of one line, so the whole length is too large:

```
\text{Variation of neutron number in time}=\text{Rate of production of neutrons}-
\text{Rate of absorption of neutrons}-\text{Rate of leakage of neutrons}
```

I tried to use a line break (cntr+enter) but it does create a new whole equation line. I cannot use it inside each text term.

Do you know how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that very simply with `stackengine`: its `\Centerstack` command is in text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily\[ \Centerstack[l]{ Variation of \\neutron number\\ in time}{}={}\Centerstack[l]{Rate of \\production\\ of neutrons}{}-{}\Centerstack[l]{Rate of\\ absorption \\ of neutrons} {}-{}\Centerstack[l]{Rate of \\leakage\\ of neutrons}\]}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! It works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could enclose each text segment in a `\pbox`. Note, this requires the `pbox` package. This way you can treat each block of text as a math object.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pbox}

\begin{document}

$\pbox{3cm}{Variation of\\ neutron number\\ in time} = \pbox{3cm}{Rate of\\ production\\ of neutrons} - \pbox{3cm}{Rate of\\ absorption\\ of neutrons}-\pbox{3cm}{Rate of\\ leakage\\ of neutrons}$

\end{document}
```

The `\pbox` will shrink its width to your text, so you only need a width that is wider than your actual width. I chose 3cm in the example.